# Blackberry application compatibility for 7.1

Tags: java, blackberry, sdk, compatibility

I have develop blackberry application using BB SDK 5.0 and tested it till 7.0 SDK and is run perfectly till 7.0.

I don't have the devices or simulator for 7.1 SDK, so is my application be able to run on 7.1 SDK also?

Thanks.

Comment: forward compatibility check? How about installing the 7.1 simulator ?

Comment: http://swdownloads.blackberry.com/Downloads/contactFormPreload.do?code=060AD92489947D410D897474079C1477&dl=DCFA2C8B2673A3FF9F8C74EC172F8A1F&check1=A

Comment: I don't want to download and install SDK. I just want if any one has done the testing for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience if you develop on SDK 5 it should run fine on anything above 5 (with the exception of 10 of course)

However, I would highly recommend you at least test on a simulator/device rather then just to assume all the functionality of your app will be there.

Comment: Ok... will run it on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [release notes](http://developer.blackberry.com/java/documentation/nitr_7_1_1970851.html) for BB SDK 7.1. This document describes most (if not all) of the significant API changes.

You can also check binary compatibility of BB SDK 7.0 and 7.1 by comparing old and new versions of all SDK JARs by the [japi-compliance-checker](https://github.com/lvc/japi-compliance-checker) tool and check if changed particular API interfaces are used by your application.