# can I run my 5.0 SDK Application to Devices having BB 7.1 OS?

Tags: blackberry, sdk

can I run my 5.0 SDK Application to Devices having BB 7.1 OS.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you open a BMW with the keys of a Ford?

Comment: @H2CO3: That is not something which is relate to this question. This is something called forward compatibility of application.
Understand the need of question and then reply.

Comment: You probably can't open a BMW with Ford keys, but you certainly **can** run BlackBerry apps written / built for OS 5.0 on OS 7.1.  Occasionally, there are things in new OS versions that actually *break* stuff that worked in old versions, so I would still recommend you test on 7.1.  But, **yes**, your app should work just fine in almost all ways.

Comment: Thanks Nate. will test it on 7.1 simulator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blackberry application compatibility for 7.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288436/blackberry-application-compatibility-for-7-1)

Comment: @H2CO3 Why the snark, especially for a platform you are so obviously ignorant of? Please delete your comment, and leave the technical details of BlackBerry to those who are actually working with the technology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can run it on BB RIM OS 7.1

But please note, that your app won't run on BB 10 platform. The most recent supported platform will be RIM OS 7.1

Also note that to provide the best user experience for end-users, compile your apps with several SDK-s using Apache Ant and BB Ant Tools. And then install on the device the most suitable version.