# Blackberry - App does not launch after signature

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Am facing an unusual problem on blackberry, after i have signed my app with the 3 keys and say "load onto device" via Eclipse Java Plugin for Blackberry - the app loads successfully on the device, but when i click on it to launch it - does not open up, nor even a error or a dialog pops up. Please Help - Cant find a solution for this!

Comment: most likely you did not sign the app correctly. Retry and make sure all signatures went well... if i remember correctly using java 7 with the signature tool creates problems when signing.

Comment: am using - blackberry jre5 - how can i identify that which version of jdk? Also when i deployed the .cod on a simulator it works fine.

Comment: the simulator doesn't require signing.

Comment: how can i identify that which version of jdk am using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2573847/1251715

Comment: Thanks! in that case my compiler compliance level is 1.3 and when i change it to 1.6 and build - the .class file creates an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have often had this issue using the 9800 device. After loading apps to the device it starts "not launching". If you go to options -> application manager -> your app's permissions you might see some permissions as custom. Setting these to "allow" fixes it. After a while it stopped launching even when allowed, deleting the app and letting the device reboot fixes it.

This is my personal experience, I don't know what the official bug/fix is

Comment: Thanks! it worked, but need not to reboot it, directly worked. Just being curious why is the permission set to "Custom" by default? Will that cause a prob each time? What are the cons for it?

Comment: I haven't been able to find the reason for it, but it's only happened on that device for me. I haven't experienced it on the 9900 or the 9380. This might be because they are OS7, where the 9800 is 6. Might be as simple as OS6 is crap buggy. As for causing a problem I don't think you need to worry. Users won't install your app multiple times like that.

Comment: Ty, also what all changes need to be made in a case when a project is developed using jre 5.0 and also needs to support for OS 7.1, can u please help out?

Comment: I have only worked in 6 and 7, sorry. I don't know any of the quirks there. But I'd suggest testing on a 5,6, and 7; since with blackberry a higher version means nothing. There are many functions introduced in 5 that don't work in 6, but work in 7 again.

Answer (score 1):

Implement logging in your application. Log every step on the application startup and [write log to a text file, located on device SD Card](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Storing_files_in_the_file_system_1219757_11.jsp).

When your application has been installed and you have tried to launch it, check this text file to find out, what is going wrong with your application.

Also there is [internal logging mechanism](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EventLogger.html), you may employ it, instead of logging to text file.

From my point of view internal log is more suitable for simple logging purposes. If you want complex logging, then text file located on SDCard is preferred.

Comment: this works on a simulator! :P but on a device, is this a java version issue?

Comment: Make sure that device RIM OS version is bigger or equals to Java SDK version you have used to compile your application.

Comment: this was working when i previously had deployed it, all a sudden this happens?

Comment: As mentioned before by @Turdnugget the reason can be related to permissions. Permissions are not required to be set when you are running your app on simulator, but when you launch it on actual device they should be set. Sometimes permissions have been requested automatically upon an action. But sometimes not. And it leads to strange things. According to your application functionality invoke permission request at startup. Use [ApplicationPermissionsManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/applicationcontrol/ApplicationPermissionsManager.html) class.

Comment: Just being curious why is the permission set to "Custom" by default? Will that cause a prob each time? What are the cons for it?

Comment: I have no idea why RIM OS does that.

Comment: you have answered here that the compatibility works on OS 7.1 - any ideas how to do that, any changes to the project properties? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288748/can-i-run-my-5-0-sdk-application-to-devices-having-bb-7-1-os

Comment: If you have compiled your application with RIM SDK 5.0, then your application will work on device with RIM OS 7.0. But the user experience [won't be good](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/13222/Controlling_compatibility_mode_705034_11.jsp). I recommend to use preprocessor and compile separate application versions for separate RIM OS versions.

Comment: am running it on a 7.1 simulator to check. As am a newbie in that case can help in how to use preprocessor and compile separate application versions for separate RIM OS versions - or if provided a pointer to it. Thanks!

Comment: Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944306/same-application-on-different-blackberry-handsets/17946504#17946504).

Answer (score 1):

Try to start the app, then check the device event log.  To open the event log viewer, hold 'Alt' and then press L,G,L,G.  You will likely see an error explaining the problem in the event log viewer.